# Null pointer exception with "setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)"

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity

Hi I'm getting `nullPointerException` in my `application` with this line.

```
this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

this.getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.GRAY));
```

I'm extending `AppCompatActivity` with my `activity class`.

My Logcat says as:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

Can you please help me clearing this issue???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the supportActionBar:

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```